# Read Grayscale 16-bit TIFF using Apache Commons Imaging (Java)

Tags: java, apache, tiff, javax.imageio

I'm trying to read in a 16-bit TIFF image (grayscale) into Java using the Apache Commons Imaging library. When I read it in using the following code:

```
TiffImageParser tip = new TiffImageParser();
BufferedImage img = tip.getBufferedImage(new File("img.tif"), null);
```

The resulting BufferedImage is of type `TYPE_INT_RGB`, not the expected `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY`. Is this due to the `TIFFImageParser` not having the correct decoder (i.e. a Apache Commons problem), or is it because I haven't set the correct parameters?

N.B. The image in question was created in Matlab using the following code:

```
img = uint16(rand(200,200) * 65535);
imwrite(img, 'img.tif');
```

Comment: Post the file here and I'll look at it, or use my TIFFTOOL to examine it and see what got created (www.bitbanksoftware.com/tinytools.htm).

Comment: Not really what you are asking for, but as you tagged your question with javax.imagio, you could try using ImageIO and my [TIFF plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff). It will read TIFF files containing 16 bit gray samples into a `TYPE_USHORT_GRAY` `BufferedImage`. If you do as @BitBank says, I'll test it for you. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was more hoping that I could do it all in Apache Commons, but it seems that Apache Commons may not support 16-bit grayscale images at all. Thanks for your suggestions.

@haraldK, Your plugin works great! Do you plan on supporting writing images into the aforementioned 16-bit grayscale format anytime soon?

Comment: @ddukki Yes, TIFF writing is on my todo-list, for the next (3.1) version. Your definition of "soon" may vary.. ;-) Not sure if writing 16 bit samples will get into the release, but I'll do my best. Feel free to ask for support in the issue tracker, or comment on the [TIFF write support](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/issues/26) case.

Comment: I am working on IMAGING-231, where a user reported issues with TIFF images, and it seems to be related to LZW compression, and also the bits per sample. There is something indeed incorrect in how we are read/decoding some files. Unfortunately I don't keep an eye on SO, but if you are still interested, feel free to raise an issue in JIRA (found this question while searching the Internet)